# How to change the width for all elements given a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the width of all div elements with a specific class. For example:

```
<div class="grid1 first">
<div class="grid2">
<div class="grid3">
<div class="grid4 last">
```

All the DIVs have initial width of 23%. DIVs with "first" or "last" class need to have additional 1% width. I tried with this code:

```
var addwidth = 0;
$("[class^=grid]").each(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("first") || $(this).hasClass("last")) {
       addwidth += $(this).width() + 1 + "%";
       $(this).width(addwidth);
   }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: you should just add another class to all these elements to adjust the width with.

Comment: `.width()` will return a computed value, i.e. its actual width in pixels.

Comment: Where do you have the `23%` specified? Javascript or css?

Comment: The initial width is in CSS. I know that .width() will return unit-less value, that's why I added %. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS if you don't need dynamic widths:

```
.first, .last {
    width: 24%;
}
```

You can calculate the widths dynamically, though you'll have to work around the fact that jQuery's `width()` and `css()` methods will return the width in pixels. To do this, you can get the width of the parent and calculate the percentage this child occupies, then update that value and set the child's width:

```
$(".first, .last").each(function () {
    var that = $(this),
        parentWidth = that.parent().width(),
        width = that.width(),
        percentage = parseInt((width/parentWidth)*100, 10)
    ;

    that.css("width", (percentage + 1) + '%');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Du3BP/)**

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I have several other elements that use different values. It can't be assigned a fixed number. In short, it needs to be calculated on the fly through JS.

Comment: Got it, I updated my answer with a dynamic way to set percentage widths using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
addwidth += $(this).width() + 1 + "%";
$(this).width(addwidth);
```

With this:

```
addwidth += $(this).width() + 1;
$(this).width(addwidth + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have set the initial width "23%" in css .
  In your code you are doing concatenation of integer and string, that wont work so split that code in two lines as below.

```
var addwidth = 0;
$("[class^=grid]").each(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("first") || $(this).hasClass("last")) {
       addwidth = parseInt($(this).css('width')) + 1;
       console.log(addwidth);
       $(this).css('width',addwidth+"%");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used that code like

$(.last).css('width',(23+1)+'%');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[class^="grid"]').each(function(i,element){
    if ( $(element).is('.first') || $(element).is('.last') ) {
    var width = ( 100 * parseFloat($(element).css('width')) / parseFloat($(element).parent().css('width')) ) + 1 + '%'
      $(element).css('width',width);
    }
})
```